# How to change text on a page? (Find and replace using jQuery?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a block of hardcoded, uneditable HTML:

```
<td id="v65-onepage-ordercomments-value" width="61%" valign="top" colspan="2">
     Order Comments:&nbsp;(Optional)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <br>           
     <textarea name="Order_Comments" id="v65-onepage-ordercomments-input" rows="3" cols="55"></textarea>
</td>
```

I want to replace "Order Comments (Optional)", as well as all those non-breaking spaces. I would preferably like to replace it with other HTML, like a header and a paragraph tag. What is the best way to do this? My assumption is to do something like a find & replace using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It it's always a textNode that is the first child of the parent div, you can do :

```
var node = document.getElementById('v65-onepage-ordercomments-value').firstChild;
node.nodeValue = 'new content';
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zJFrD/12/)

or in jQuery:

```
$('#v65-onepage-ordercomments-value').contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType===3 && this.nodeValue.trim().length) 
        this.nodeValue = 'new content';
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zJFrD/13/)

Comment: although this does definitely work, he requested a jQuery answer.  Could you provide both?

Comment: adeneo, here's a fiddle of the answer. Doesn't seem to work. http://jsfiddle.net/pKVZB/

Comment: Hmm, the first block of code adds the new text underneath the old one, but doesn't get rid of the old one. And the second block of code doesn't seem to have any effect at all. It doesn't NEED to be jQuery, and it seems like the plain JS is closer to the solution anyway.

Comment: @user1925805 - now I had to test the code in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE9, and it replaces the textnode correctly in all browsers for me. What browser are you using ?

Comment: @adeneo I'm using Chrome. Here's a curious thing: When I use the plain JS code in it's own script tag, it has no effect. Only when I place it in a script tag that first checks for the specific url (which specifically is: "$(function() { if (location.pathname == "/one-page-checkout.asp") {") does it add the text, but still not replace the old text. Is there any other information I could give you that would be helpful?

Comment: You need to add the script after the elements in the DOM, otherwise the elements aren't accessible, as there is no DOM ready function. Does the fiddle not work, or is the issue with the text being added below the original text only on your page.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this but something like this should work:

```
var text = $("#v65-onepage-ordercomments-value").text();
var newText = text.replace("Order Comments:&nbsp;(Optional)", "<p>Sup?</p>");
$("#v65-onepage-ordercomments-value").text(newText); // .html(newText) is also viable.
```

Comment: What does `string()` do, and wouldn't that remove all the elements ?