# Checking whether an HTML element contains primitive text?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Take this HTML:

```
<div id="el1">
  <div id="el2">
    <div id="el3">
      Hello
      <div id="el4">
        World
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that `el3` and `el4` contain primitive text; namely "Hello" and "World". The other elements (`el1` and `el2`) only contain other elements.

And yet, using pure JavaScript, all of their `innerHTML` properties indicate they contain some form of text.

How can one use pure JavaScript to ascertain whether a particular element contains primitive text as a child. In this instance, the method would also recognise `el3` as containing primitive text (even though it also contains another element thereafter).

Something like this:

```
var els = getElementByTagName("*");

for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){

  if( /* element contains text */ ){

    // do something

  }
}
```

Is this really just a job for RegEx? With all the properties of an HTMLElement, you'd think there would be a better way.

No jQuery, thanks.

Comment: Define “primitive text”. All the elements in the example contain text nodes. Instead of using an invented expression like “primitive text” without a definition, you should define the test you wish to perform. Perhaps you wish to test whether an element contains text nodes that have content other than whitespace characters? Then you would just need to define which characters should be treated as whitespace characters, and the rest is simple coding.

Comment: You're a bit late to the party. Considering three answers, all competent, have been put forward suggests that most people understood my "invented expression". If I had known the ins and outs of the DOM, then perhaps I would have been able to articulate "text nodes with content other than whitespace". But, I decided to try and describe what I was after and hope that someone more imaginative might be able to understand what I meant. Thankfully, they did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

innerHTML gets the HTML, and all of the elements except the last one contains HTML as they are nested.

For instance, the innerHTML of `#el2` would be

```
  <div id="el3">
      Hello
      <div id="el4">
          World
      </div>
  </div>
```

To get just the text, modern browsers support either `innerText` or `textContent` (firefox).
Then there's whitespace, so you should probably trim() the text as well, so something like this

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll("#wrapper *");

for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
    var el = els[i].cloneNode(true);
    var children = el.children;

    for (var j=children.length; j--;) el.removeChild(children[j]);
    var content = el.innerText ? el.innerText  : el.textContent;

    if( content.trim().length ){
        // do something
        console.log(els[i].getAttribute('id') + ' has text');
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jXL7H/2/)

Or checking the nodeType and nodeValue of text nodes

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll("#wrapper *");

for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
    var el = els[i];
    var children = el.childNodes;

    for (var j=children.length; j--;) {
        if( children[j].nodeType === 3 && children[j].nodeValue.trim().length) {
            // do something
            console.log(els[i].getAttribute('id') + ' has text');
        }
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jXL7H/4/)

Comment: This won't work. I'm aware that `innerHTML` contains everything below the chosen element, but `innerText` and `textContent` are no substitute as they still indicate that there is text further down the DOM tree, even if the element itself does not contain text.

Comment: Then just remove the children, and then check if the element contains text.

Comment: Thanks for updating your code. For the record, I think your second example (inspired by Dawn's suggestion of inspecting the `nodeType` property) is a better approach.

Comment: @shennan - It's a common way to check for textContent, [especially in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861168/how-to-change-text-on-a-page-find-and-replace-using-jquery) so there's no magic there, and I do agree, checking the nodes is better than cloning and removing the children.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how you can use the `nodeType` to help you get your answer:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    var hasTextNode = false;
    var currChildren = els[i].childNodes;

    for (var j = 0; j < currChildren.length; j++) {
        if ((currChildren[j].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) &&
            (!(/^\s*$/.test(currChildren[j].textContent)))) {
                hasTextNode = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    window.console.log(els[i].id + ((hasTextNode) ? " has" : " does not have") + " a Text Node");
}
```

Applying that to the HTML that you provided results in this in the console:

```
el1 does not have a Text Node
el2 does not have a Text Node
el3 has a Text Node
el4 has a Text Node
```

**Note:** it is important to check the found Text Nodes for "space only" content, because the DOM will consider all of the indenting and line breaks in the source code as a "Text Node".  Obviously, you would want to ignore those.

Comment: I like your comparison to a constant `Node.TEXT_NODE` and your `break` clause for efficiency. Could you describe your use of regex?

Comment: Sure . . . the regex pattern basically looks from the beginning to the end of the text in the node (`^` - beginning, `$` - end) and checks to see if the entire text is made up of 0 or more (`*` - 0 or more) whitespace characters (`\s` - whitespace characters).  If it is all whitespaces, then the assumption is that the text node is simply the result of source code formatting.  If it is **not** all whitespace characters, then the assumption is that it contains intentional text content.

Comment: Fab, thanks again. +1'd. I'm going to give the answer @adeneo as he was the first to give a working example. But I'll apply some of your techniques too. Cheers.

Comment: It won't be the first time that **adeneo** has beat me to the punch.   :D

Comment: Out of interest, is there any difference between using your RegEx test, vs. using the `trim` method?

Comment: In this case, they effectively accomplish the same thing . . . what ".trim()` does is remove all leading and trailing whitespaces from a string value . . . when adeneo uses that and then checks the length, he is basically saying "When I trim out all of the whitespace characters, is there anything left?".  Functionally, that ends up testing for the same thing as my regex checking to see if the string only contains whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

you tell the difference between element nodes and text nodes via the nodeType property.  myelementnode.nodeType will return 1, mytextnode.nodeType will return 3.

as the name suggests, getElementsByTagName will only give you element nodes.  what you want to do is use the childNodes property of your root node, which will get you all immediate children of that node as a nodelist. so, for el1 you will get just the one child node, el2.

you then have to recursively go through each child node to get its children until you hit a node with type 3 - text.

so for el3, it will return 2 child nodes.  The first will be your text, the second will be your el4 element.  You'd then need to go into el4 to get its child node.

innerHTML returns a string (of a chunk of html converted to a string), not nodes.  you could use that and a regular expression to discard everything that sits within < and >, but that is a bit crude, and with large chunks of html will be an expensive process.

Comment: Yeah, was trying to avoid complex regex. I've +1'd, but I'll award you the answer if you can give me a dom-traversing example for clarification? Something that ties in with the HTML outlined in the question. :-)